# Symfony 5 VichUploaderBundler : The type hint of parameter "imageFile" in method "setImageFile" in class "App\Entity\xxx" is invalid

Tags: symfony, parameters, production-environment, type-hinting, vichuploaderbundle

During a production cache clear I have this message :    The type hint of parameter "imageFile" in method "setImageFile" in class "App\Entity\Evenement" is invalid. I follow the instruction of the VichUploaderBundle's documentation on github "basic usage".
Thanks for your help !

below the code of the entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EvenementRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EvenementRepository::class)
 * @vich\Uploadable
 */
class Evenement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Url()
     */
    private $visuel;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="evenement", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     * @var File|null
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     */
    private $tarifs;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Film::class, inversedBy="evenements")
     */
    private $films;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateFin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $video;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->films = new ArrayCollection();
    }




    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre(string $titre): self
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVisuel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->visuel;
    }

    public function setVisuel(?string $visuel): self
    {
        $this->visuel = $visuel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTarifs(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tarifs;
    }

    public function setTarifs(?string $tarifs): self
    {
        $this->tarifs = $tarifs;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Film[]
     */
    public function getFilms(): Collection
    {
        return $this->films;
    }

    public function addFilm(Film $film): self
    {
        if (!$this->films->contains($film)) {
            $this->films[] = $film;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFilm(Film $film): self
    {
        $this->films->removeElement($film);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateFin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateFin;
    }

    public function setDateFin(?\DateTimeInterface $dateFin): self
    {
        $this->dateFin = $dateFin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVideo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->video;
    }

    public function setVideo(?string $video): self
    {
        $this->video = $video;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImageName(?string $imageName): void
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
    }

    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Olivv, Please try cache clear of dev mod

Comment: Hello Ravi, cache clear of dev mod works localy and on the server but cache clear of prod mod doesn't work, localy and on the server.

Comment: DId you try `rm -rf var/cache/*` on prod server?

Comment: It work in that way. I had also to upload the Proxies directory after having "rm -rf var/cache/*" . But now,  how do I get the "php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod" command to work again?

Comment: after `rm -rf /var/cache/*` try `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` command

Comment: I have the same message :                                                                                                     
  The type hint of parameter "imageFile" in method "setImageFile" in class "App\Entity\Evenement" is   
   invalid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Please set your fields according to this

Note: Don't forgot to update your database

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity\File as EmbeddedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

  /**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="51200k",
 *     mimeTypes = {
 *       "image/jpeg",
 *       "image/gif",
 *       "image/png",
 *     }
 * )
 * @Vich\UploadableField(
 *      mapping="evenement_image",
 *      fileNameProperty="imageFile.name",
 *      size="imageFile.size",
 *      originalName="imageFile.originalName",
 *      mimeType="imageFile.mimeType"
 * )
 *
 * @var File|null
 */
protected $image;

/**
 * @ORM\Embedded(class="Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity\File")
 *
 * @var EmbeddedFile
 */
protected $imageFile;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->imageFile = new EmbeddedFile();
}

public function setImage(?File $image = null): void
{
    $this->image = $image;

    if (null !== $image) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
    }
}

public function getImage(): ?File
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function getImageFile(): ?EmbeddedFile
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

public function setImageFile(EmbeddedFile $imageFile): self
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I still have the message : "The type hint of parameter "image" in method "setImage" in class "App\Entity\Evenement" is invalid."

Comment: I still have the message : "The type hint of parameter "image" in method "setImage" in class "App\Entity\Evenement" is invalid." I also have "Given object is not an instance of the class this property was declared in" when I submit the form with the picture. For info in the form builder there is : ->add('image', VichImageType::class, [...